# which is better way to returning structure from function?

Tags: c, structure, return-value

there are various ways to return structure from function like return whole structure or return the pointer only.
returning pointer is useful to avoid stack overhead as we don't needed to return whole structure. In other side for 
small structure it is good to go with returning whole structure.

In my case i have below scenario to get structure from another file and thought various methods to use but as i am new to C so still i needed some expert advise like

which method is better? Any issue in it? or any suggestion for new method?

returning large structure as whole cause any stack issue?

**file1.c**

```
static struct_type mysruct; //Note : here struct size is 250+ bytes

//Method 1
struct_type getStructDataMethod1()
{
    return mysruct;
}

//Method 2
void getStructDataMethod2(struct_type *structPtr)
{
    if(structPtr != NULL)
    {
        memcpy(structPtr, &mysruct, sizeof(struct_type));
    }
}
//Method 3
void getStructDataMethod3(struct_type *structPtr)
{
    *structPtr = mysruct;
}
```

**file2.c**

```
void myFunction()
{
    struct_type mylocalStruct1 = getStructDataMethod1();
    struct_type mylocalStruct2;
    struct_type mylocalStruct3;

    getStructDataMethod2(&mylocalStruct2);
    getStructDataMethod3(&mylocalStruct3);

}
```

Comment: Method2/3 gives the caller explicit control over the life of the struct without having to rely on a static declaration elsewhere. Otherwise -- it's basically a wash. Copying occurs in all 3 cases. (either you do it, or the copying is handled implicitly)

Comment: `getStructDataMethod2()` and `getStructDataMethod3()` are equivalent (minus the `NULL` check).

Comment: @pmg Yes but i thought third method to avoid call of memcpy.

Comment: Another option is to use global variables (but try hard to use one of the options you introduced: global variables can easily become a management headache).

Comment: @pmg yes managing global is difficult, that's why i limited scope of  **mystruct** to file1.c and introduced get API for it.

Comment: If it's only to read the structure why about return const pointer to the static struct ? Like this:
`
const * struct_type getStructDataMethod1()
{
    return &mysruct;
}
`
This is what I use for big config structure to prevent global variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule of thumb is to always pass structs to function by pointers and never by value, for the reasons you mention yourself. You should only make special case exceptions to this rule in case a struct is very small.

So either method 2 or 3 is the correct way to do it. Apart from the NULL pointer check, they are equivalent.

---

Minor issue not related to your question: never write functions as `void myFunction()` in C, this is obsolete style. Use `void myFunction(void)` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so the call of 'memcpy' in method2 make no difference? like performance wise "=" is faster or "memcpy"? or internally same thing done?

Comment: @user2520119 Unless the compiler is broken, it should yield the same machine code for memcpy as for the struct assignment. See for yourself: https://godbolt.org/z/RoadXK